# How to make a role through reactions in discord.js?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I've been at this all morning. I'm currently working on a function that effectively creates a role, with one click on a reaction, but it has been throwing up the same error for a lifetime now.

Here's my code:

```
    client.on('message', async message => {
let AdminRole = message.member.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Server Moderators")
let RulerRole = message.member.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "The Supreme Boomers")
let RatRole = message.member.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Rat Majesty Robin")
if (message.member.roles.cache.has(AdminRole)) {
} else if (message.member.roles.cache.has(RulerRole)) {
} else if (message.member.roles.cache.has(RatRole)) {
}
if (message.content === `${prefix}createBumpRole`) {

 message.channel.send("Do you want to create a role for bumping? Click on either the check mark or cross depending on your choice.")
 message.react("✅") | message.react("❌")
}
const filter = (reaction, user) => {
    return ['✅', '❌'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id;
};
message.awaitReactions(filter, { max: 1, time: 60000, errors: ['time'] })
.then(collected => {
    const reaction = collected.first();
    
    if (reaction.emoji.name === '✅') {
       
        message.guild.cache.roles.create({
            data: {
              name: 'bumping ping',
              color: 'BLUE',
            },
            reason: 'We needed a role for people who regularly bump the server.',
          })
        
    } else if (reaction.emoji.name === '❌') {
        message.reply('Thank you for the response. You have exited this program.');
    }
})
```

});

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: We need to know what error you're getting and what line it references to help you.

Comment: I am getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined

Comment: Which line is that error referencing.

Comment: It is referencing to the message.guild.roles.cache.create line